# Can't infer type for lambda?

Tags: type-checking, idris

I am trying to understand the TinyIdris code for type-checking [here](https://github.com/edwinb/SPLV20/blob/master/TinyIdris-v2/src/TTImp/Elab/Term.idr). The main function `checkTerm` handles type inference for lambda abstractions by directing throwing an error:

```
checkTerm env (ILam p mn argTy scope) Nothing
    = throw (GenericMsg "Can't infer type for lambda")
```

But a few lines below, the code does not seem to have problems with type-inferencing a Pi ($\Pi$) abstraction.

I read that for untyped lambda calculus, there are some terms that can cause problems for typing, such as $\lambda x.x~x$. But the above code seems to imply that there is also an issue for type-inferencing with typed labmdas. I am not really familiar with the theories.

*Can someone help explain why we can't infer type for lambda?*

*Is this generally true, or is it just not needed in TinyIdris/Idirs?*

*Why is it OK to type-inference $\Pi$'s while we can't infer type for $\lambda$?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty with inferring a type for a lambda is knowing what type to assign the argument. Sometimes you can look at how the variable is used to infer this, which is what Hindley Milner or other constraint based systems do.

But in this case, we take a type for the argument as a field of `ILam`. So the assumption is that every function is annotated with the type of its argument.
Once we know that, we can just recursively infer a type for the body like we would with any other term.

In the case that a lambda has no ascription, I'm guessing Idris just adds a fresh unification variable as its type. I'm not sure how much of this TinyIdris does.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to Joey's answer. The reason why we *can* infer $\Pi$ is that the type of pi is just universe, where the level is computed from the components' levels, an no dependency has to be taken care of.

This is infinitely times easier than computing the type of $\lambda$ terms, which is a *dependent type*, which requires higher-order unification to do inference on.